# Convert React global functions to use context instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have the following in my codebase right now:

```
export const myState = {
    mylist: [],
}

export function flagSomething(default) {
    myState.mylist.map((i) => {
        i.setFlag(true)
        i.setInitial(default)
    })
}

export function unflagSomething(default) {
    myState.mylist.map((i) => {
        i.setFlag(false)
        i.setInitial(default)
    })
}
```

Basically just a file that has global functions to change the values of a global variable. How can I use React context to make this available "globally", but without actually polluting my global namespace? Thanks for any help!

Comment: That would be a good fit for a reducer (for the actions) stuffed into context. I have an example of such a construct over at https://codesandbox.io/s/kekkonen-global-state-80hnd (or https://github.com/akx/kekkonen) – but you might want to look at something more established, like https://zustand.surge.sh/

Comment: @AKX Hmm thank you, could you write an answer using reducers please? Would definitely help me understand a lot better.

Comment: Maybe look at the example for Zustand :)

Comment: `polluting my global namespace`  If your using modules, your not polluting the global namespace.  The only advantage of a Context here is if you wanted multiple instances with different context state based on your render layout.

Comment: `myState.mylist.map`  your not returning the newly created array here, you maybe meant `forEach`